# Remove Unnecesary Maven Dependencies from Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, spring-boot, maven, ffmpeg, jar

I am working with Spring-Boot 2.3.8 and Eclipse.

I am using these dependencies to work  on some videos:

```
    <!-- javacv -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
        <artifactId>javacv</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--opencv-platform -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
        <artifactId>opencv-platform</artifactId>
        <version>4.4.0-1.5.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- ffmpeg-platform -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
        <artifactId>ffmpeg-platform</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.1-1.5.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

Eclipse is adding all JARs of opencv, javaccp and ffmpeg, including JARs for Androind, MacOs, etc. I just need the ones for Windows and the problem is that these extra dependencies are creating problems for my teams when they try to load the project, build or test it (it is extreamly slow or just doesnt work).

These dependencies are not present in my final WAR when I build with maven form the command line and I use:

```
mvn -Djavacpp.platform=windows-x86_64 clean install
```

Is there a way to tell eclipse to do the same?

The WAR size goes from 800 MB to around 200 MB when building without and with and the platform flag, these extra 600 MB are what in my opinion is too much for eclipse.

Here is an image of all the JARs being added to the project.

[image: List of JARs]

Comment: In the case of M2Eclipse, it looks like we have to put those properties in the eclipse.ini file: https://www.eclipse.org/lists/m2e-dev/msg01709.html

Comment: @SamuelAudet pointed me in the right direction, I was able to limit the dependencies to just windows-x86 by adding -Djavacpp.platform=windows-x86 to eclipse.ini. I tried to use other platforms by following the documentation but it did not work. https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp-presets/wiki/Reducing-the-Number-of-Dependencies